# How can I get specific rows in a table by the value of a specific queried column of a different table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, subquery, sql-view

I have the `Table1` and the `Table2` tables. `Table1` has the `B` (Primary Key) and `IC` columns. `Table2` has the `CC`, `SC` and `IC` columns:

### Table `Table1`

| ... | B | IC | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ... | B1 | IC1 | ... |

### Table `Table2`

| ... | CC | SC | IC | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ... | CC1 | SC1 | IC1 | ... |
| ... | CC1 | SC2 | IC1 | ... |
| ... | CC2 | SC1 | IC1 | ... |
| ... | CC2 | SC2 | IC1 | ... |

I want to query `Table1`, filtering its rows by a value of the `B` column. After finding the row (and I find only one since `B` is PK), I want to use the corresponding value of the `IC` column to query for the rows in `Table2` that have the same `IC` value as the one of the `IC` column obtained from the first step. So, I want to filter these rows by specific `CC` and `SC` values.

The above representations explain the concept:

1. I query `Table1` for the rows whose `B` value is `B1`.
2. I get that the corresponding `IC` value is `IC1`.
3. I query `Table2` for the rows whose `IC` value is identical to the previous one, `IC1`, and I want to filter the found rows by the specific `CC2` and `SC1` values. So, the desired result, in this case, is the third row of `Table2`.

They tell me to use views when I can. I know that I can’t pass inputs to a view; moreover, I don’t want to use stored procedures. How can I create a view to get all the `Table2` rows whose `IC` value is obtained from the `Table1`’s `IC` column, and filter these rows by specific `CC` and `SC` values? Maybe I need to use subqueries instead? Do I need to use joins? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sounds like you are asking for a simple `inner join`, you can create a `view` that does this and then apply your filtering criteria to the view - it's not completely clear from your description so add desired results to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly then you can try this

```
SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE IC = (SELECT IC FROM table1 WHERE B='B1')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use both join and subquery, if you are going to use join make sure you have to defined proper indexes for the table otherwise your query is going to be slow.
Sub Query example:

```
CREATE VIEW [VIEW NAME] AS
SELECT * FORM Table2 WHERE IC IN (SELECT IC FROM Table1 where B = 'B1')
```

Comment: there will be always one value of IC corresponding to B1 in table1. No need to use in clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `WHERE` to filter on the primary key and an (inner) `JOIN` on the `IC` columns to get the according rows from `Table2`. Since you only want them, I used `t2.*` in the `SELECT`. If you also want the columns from `Table1`, use `SELECT *` instead.

```
SELECT t2.* 
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN Table2 t2
ON t1.IC = t2.IC
WHERE t1.B = 'B1'
AND t2.CC = 'CC1'
```

You can add any additional filters in the `WHERE` clause.

If you want to make this into a view, simply put

```
CREATE VIEW myviewname AS
```

before the above `SELECT` query without the parts of the `WHERE` clause that you want to be able to vary and use e.g.

```
SELECT * 
FROM myviewname v
WHERE v.CC = 'CC1'
```

to apply that filter part on the view.